# when there is no value make the value null

Tags: java, android, methods

sometimes I need the values to be null.
For example:

```
Switch(animal.getId(){
    case animal.equals("dog"){
        String size=small;
        String fur=fluffy;
        placement(size,fur);
        break;
    }
    case animal.equals("lizard"){
        String size=small;
        placement(size);
        break;
    }

public void placement(String size, String fur){
    System.println("Size: "+size);
    System.println("Fur: +fur);
}
```

If animal equals dog it works fine.  however if animals equals lizard I need the Fur to come up as Null, or none.  I'm attempting to just have null values for when the data is not needed.  If I can't then I guess I'll just have put in all the data and have the default  saved as     `String fur="none"`     and place     `placement(size,fur)`     for each time it's called.

Comment: Is this supposed to be Java? Because it isn't. And what does the posted code have to do with SQL?

Comment: The question is if I do not have a Fur string I want it to return as none or null or something so I don't have to make more Strings than necessary.  It was solved by having      '    Placement(size,null)     '    which gives the String fur as null.
Also Ted Hopp thank you for the answer!  It wasn't needed and I deleted the part of the question.  I am working with SQL and making a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to have optional arguments in Java is to overload the method name. In your case, you can have two `placement` methods:

```
public void placement(String size){
    placement(size, null);
}
public void placement(String size, String fur){
    System.println("Size: "+size);
    System.println("Fur: +fur);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! didn't know that I could just say null.  I was worried I would have to make many more than necessary strings for each argument!  That and I couldn't find the name for this type of calling.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this already helps:

```
Switch(animal.getId(){
  case animal.equals("dog"){
    String size=small;
    String fur=fluffy;
    placement(size,fur);
    break;
  }
  case animal.equals("lizard"){
    String size=small;
    placement(size, null);
    break;
  }
}

public void placement(String size, String fur){
  if (size != null)
    System.println("Size: "+size);

  if (fur != null)
    System.println("Fur: +fur);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! didn't know that I could just say null. I was worried I would have to make many more than necessary strings for each argument! That and I couldn't find the name for this type of calling.